# How do you create the packed_trx field when submitting a transaction to the chain?

Tags: transactions, rpc

When submitting a signed transaction to the chain via the RPC interface, I get an error about an "Invalid packed transaction".  What is the process for packing a transaction for submission to the chain?

Answer (score 1):

[EOSDevHelper](https://github.com/OracleChain/EOSDevHelper/blob/master/src/push/pushframe.cpp#L105) packed transaction and push to nodeos. And [here](https://github.com/OracleChain/chainkit/blob/9a537045d8ec9f0778fa9bf02afb232efad829db/chain/packedtransaction.cpp) is details of how to implement.

Comment: do you have detailed steps for generate the packed_trx? not just c++ code